# Firebase blaze plan related query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am a developer of android apps, actively I am using spark(free) plan of FireBase, which gives me 100 simultaneous users and 10 GB Realtime Database(download data), but now I need more simultaneous users for my app minimum 1000 users and also some Firebase Database Storage. I don't need realtime database (bandwidth). So I decided to go for blaze plan instead of flame one.

I wants to ask that if I would pay for the Firebase Realtime database storage then simultaneous users will be increased or not?

Also will I have to pay for Realtime database (Gb downloaded) or it will be continued till I exceed the limit of the free plan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All features in that project are under the same billing plan/pricing tier. You cannot selectively upgrade one feature and leave another on the free tier.

If you're on the metered plan, you have the same free quota as you'd have on the free plan. You only pay for the Database and all Storage usage that is over that free quota, at the rate that is indicated in the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: In the blaze plan you can "selectively" choose to extend the metrics you need more of, all the while using the free limits from the free plan. The question was that if we choose the blaze plan (and use it within the free limits), will we get paid for the increased simultaneous connections (100 to 100k) because this metric is not present in blaze plan pricing calculator.

Comment: You can only upgrade an entire project, not a single feature. The simultaneous connections are not in the calculator because it's not charged by volume, but merely a limit. If you think you have a better answer, provide your own answer please. Your comment+downvote did make me notice that the last paragraph is outdated, as there *is* nowadays a free quota on the blaze plan. So I updated my answer that to reflect that.